# How to create a named profile on EDB Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-9.6

Could someone guide how to create following profile define rules in EDB Postgresql:

1. count failed login attempts
2. lock an account due to excessive failed login attempts
3. define rules for password complexity
4. define rules that limit password re-use

Comment: What do you mean with "profile"? Postgres has roles not "profiles". Did you even bother to read [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) before asking this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you confuse Oracle profiles:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admusers.htm#i1007119

with PostgresEDB roles:

https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/10/pg/user-manag.html

which have no profiles...

What you could check instead is postgresql role as is:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html

`CONNECTION LIMIT` and `VALID UNTIL` are somewhat similar to Oracle profiles, but also they are very different - worth of reading